My Solana Blink not working correctly
I'm building where when user clicks on button it get the NFT in their wallet, the app integration is working correctly but the NFT is not visible in the wallet.
here is the github link - https://github.com/imvisp/Birthday-blink-chris.git


did you check the chain to see if the transaction actually landed?
is the NFT being hidden in the spam filter? this is especially common with cNFTs


Yes, I am doing this transaction via an empty wallet.
So, it's not hidden and the transaction is also landed.

But you don't mint anything in the route.ts file, do you? You have the MEMO transaction there.
You need to update the POST handler.
By the way, here is the good tutorial (however, it's not about NFT, but may be useful as well):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYdO2AJ7wvI
